# Not getting time difference using MomentJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, angular-moment

Hey guys I'm trying get the difference of time using *MomentJS* so I can build a countdown clock.
The problem is that I'm getting this error:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>   Arguments: 
>   [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 00:00, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

My console.log is `NaN`

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the TS:

```
now: any;

ngOnInit() {
     this.now = parseInt(moment().format('h'));
}
///
startTimer() {
    const endTime = moment('10AM', ['h:mm A']).format('HH:mm');
    const a = moment(this.now, 'HHmm').diff(endTime, 'hours');
    console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: don't confuse warnings with errors.  That is merely telling you that someday that function will be removed.  In the meantime it will still work.

Comment: Hey @JohnLord thanks, you're right, I was focusing on the console.log results. Thanks thou :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly u need to take now inside to function , if not your end iss constant. then how can it count.

```
startTimer(from,to){
    const now = moment(from, ['h:mm A']).format('H:mm:ss')
    const end = moment(to, ['h:mm A']).format('H:mm:ss');
    var a ;
    if(now>end){
            a = moment.utc(moment(now,['H:mm']).diff(moment(end,['H:mm']))).format("H:mm");
    }
    else{
          a ="-"+ moment.utc(moment(end,['H:mm']).diff(moment(now,['H:mm']))).format("H:mm");
    }
    return a
}
```

call `startTimer('11AM','2PM')` in your html page

Comment: Hey @Çağrı thank you but the result is not correct :( So if `const now = '11:00:00'`, `const endTime =  14:00:00`  the difference should be `3:00:00` right? But I'm getting '18:29' instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use subtract instead of diff like so:

```
const endTime = moment('10:00 AM', ['h:mm A']).format('HH:mm');
const a = moment(moment(this.now, 'h:mm A').subtract(endTime, 'hours')).format('hh');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Hey @Sharanya thanks, but this is not returning the correct result either. So if my end time is 2PM and now is 11am, the result is coming as 11 instead of 3